# Finding the amount of memory allocated for the environment output by cmdstanr sampling

Tags: r, memory, stan, rstan

Assigning the output of a call to the `sample()` method of a compiled model from the `cmdstanr` package produces an "environment" in my global environment rather than a model object. Is there some way to see how much memory this environment is using?

For example:

```r
library(cmdstanr)

# Compile an arbitrary model (model needed)
mod <- cmdstan_model(stan_file = "foo.stan")

# Fit model (data needed)
fit <- mod$sample(
  data = bar)
```

In this case, `fit` is an `environment` in my RStudio global environment. Typical objects will show their size in the RStudio environment explorer, but this does not. I'd like to see how much RAM it's occupying.

Comment: Two comments: (1) `cmdstan_model` simply stores the paths to the Stan executable, Stan model and compiled model executable. There should be no significant memory footprint at  all. (2) I wouldn't overwrite `mod` when you sample (better to store as e.g. `fit`). The `$sample()` method creates R6 `CmdStanMCMC` objects, which are different from the R6 object returned by `cmdstan_model`. What does `object.size()` on the output of `$sample()` give you?

Comment: you could use `cmdstan` [profiling](https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/articles/profiling.html).

Comment: @Waldi That page and the one it links to don't actually have anything on memory profiling -- there's a section about "memory" but it puzzling doesn't actually discuss it as far as I can tell.

Comment: Agree, chain_stack gives the number of objects allocated, but not their size...